# Installing php extension broke my web service - page source is correct but not displaying

Tags: php, http, apc, apt-get

I attempted to install apc on my ubuntu 12.04 server. It worked, but I noticed that after installation, (using apt-get install ... ) the page no longer compiled correctly.

I looked in my error.log but I am not getting errors like I normally do. It appears to be compiling the php perfectly as normal. Also an IDENTICAL php file running on my local server works perfectly still.

I fully uninstalled apc (using apt-get remove & checking through php.ini), but it did not revert to its previous state. I think it may have something to do with buffering or an http client configuration error? I turned buffering on & restarted but it still doesn't work.

Are there any settings any of you might recommend? The source that the page outputs is the following:

```
 Invalid request, be sure to set all necessary keys.
```

Normally that shows up on the screen, but now the screen is just completely white.

Any ideas about what may have happened? I am hesitant to post the code or website address fully because it contains access to a database with confidential information.

EDIT: 
The page is returning a 404 page error.

Comment: Try compiling the source from your modified php interpreter.  There may be things that need altering in the php config.
`apt-get remove` doesn't always revert config files.

Comment: I attempted recompiling but I was not met with success, could you give me more specific instructions on how to recompile?

Comment: Added the page error I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### To investigate the change to the interpreter

Every noun that I type starting with a dollar sign, is a representation of a variable.
I could make guesses but this is likely to make the analysis more complex.
When I write "$afile", type one of the filenames in, from the previous listing.

```
login to your server (i am assuming SSH to a Unix box)
cd $whatever_your_doc_root_is
find . -name '*.php'
# this should give you a biiiiig list of files
php -l $afile
# should report any errors
```

The interesting errors don't have a line number or file name on them, and say "missing extension $blah" or similar.

```
# edit the file you just compiled to have the following at the top
# this is untested, but looks correct...

error_reporting(-1);
# bool handler ( int $errno , string $errstr [, string $errfile [, int $errline [, array $errcontext ]]] )
function h1($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
     echo("$errfile#$errline: [$errno]$errstr\n");
     return true; 
} 
set_error_handler('h1');
```

then run individual files that don't alter the database or whatever.

To compile ALL the source

```
for x in `find . -name '*.php' ` do php -l $x; done
```

...This should run quite fast

Comment: When I run the command php -l $afile, it freezes. Let it sit for an hour, and it won't stop going.

Comment: You did use "minus ell"? It just compiles the code, it doesn't run it.  Your webpages are blank for the reason that this doesn't compile.  Got any logging?

Comment: I did use the same command that you specified. It doesn't show anything or end the line, it freezes, and never prompts me unless I use ctrl+C to quit the command. Is that the expected result?

Comment: no, I have never seen PHP code compilation take more than 1s. Just for comparison, can you compile something on another box?  hangon, you don't use bash do you? I will update the notes

Comment: Is there a way to automate this for each file or do I have to do it for each manually?

Comment: We are looking at the PHP interpreter, not the source. We only need to compile 1 file, to see the error messages.

Comment: Well when I run php -l index.php (my file), it simply returns that it has no syntax errors.

Comment: the thing says we should use a chat window

Comment: I cannot use the chat yet, my reputation is too low.